# How to securely connect to MySQL database on another server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, discord.js

I'm attempting to link my Discord bot with a MySQL database that is on another server. However, this example is apparently insecure:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'hostname',
  port     : 'portnum',
  user     : 'db_user',
  password : 'db_user_password',
  database : 'db_name',
  charset  : 'utf8mb4'
});
```

How would I go about establishing a (more) secure connection?

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer here.

If you'd like to learn more about Javascript, I'd suggest [Mozilla's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). If you'd like to learn more about node, refer to [its documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/). If you'd like to learn more about the `mysql` npm module, refer to [its documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If its a hosted database server and you have the secured endpoint URL (meaning https:// host) then just use that as the hostname `host: 'hostname'` and that should be enough.

If it's a private server that you own and you have the SSL certificates then you can use the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'passw0rd',
    database: 'test',
    ssl: {
        ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/ca.pem'),
        key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/client-key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/client-cert.pem')
    }
});

connection.connect();
```

Comment: It has SSL certificates, but I don't own the physical server, only a right to use it. As I've said below the server is the same server for a publicly accessible server (www.emirates-virtual.com).

Comment: You may want to edit the question to include that if it's preventing solutions from working.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect using SSL using something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'hostname',
  port     : 'portnum',
  user     : 'db_user',
  password : 'db_user_password',
  database : 'db_name',
  charset  : 'utf8mb4',
  ssl: {
      ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/ca.pem'),
      key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/client-key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/client-cert.pem')
  }
});
```

You must also enable SSL on the MySql server. There are some [tutorials](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-enable-ssl-and-remote-connections-for-mysql-on-centos-7/) online showing how to, but you would need root access to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really insecure. You have a couple of options.  First, are the servers on a private network behind a firewall?  Or are they only able to connect with each other over public ip address?  If the former is true, you are fine. I would however add firewall rules on the server so that it only allows connections from the other machine. If they are connecting on public IP addresses, you'll need to do the same and also use a non-standard port for MySQL.  You can also add another NIC and bind the MySQL service to that.  This way if hackers discover your server, it will appear to have all ports closed.

Comment: The server is the same server for a publicly accessible server (www.emirates-virtual.com).

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu?  If so, what version?  Also, are these dedicated or virtual servers?  You won't be able to do this in a shared environment. Finally, do you have root access?

Comment: I think the server is running is running Linux but I’ll find the version. I have root access but I’m not sure if the server is virtual or dedicated. I will contact the host to find out

Comment: Cool. Let  me know.

Comment: Hello, I found out that the server is a dedicated server

Comment: If you have root access, you should definitely be able to secure it.  I would need access to the servers in order to configure them.